# Can't load three.js animations after deploying it on Github

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I made a basic portfolio website using `main.js` It works fine on the local server but when I upload the code to GitHub and deploy it, it doesn't work.

I only see `HTML` and `CSS` files but the `main.js` files won't load. I even tried using gh-pages and creating a dist folder but it still doesn't work.

My console has the following error:

```bash
THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created.
```

How can I fix this?
Here's [my code](https://github.com/elfa6/Ayla.git)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There's little to go on, as it's unclear how you did the build and deployment to Github. My guess is that the build is faulty; maybe three.js or WebGL needs to be explicitly exported in the build.

Comment: The "three.js" file ? Do you mean the one in the asset folder ? If yes, why is it in a folder called asset ? Your index.548483ff.js file is barely readable. I believe you did a copy/paste of a huge shader. 
Where is the line where you're linking the canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.548483ff.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.4db4f50e.css">
```

Both paths are not correct. You want to use:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index.548483ff.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index.4db4f50e.css">
```

The additional dot ensures the path starts relative from the current location and not from the host.